# How handle javascript redirect and change it

Tags: javascript, html

I would like handle a javascript redirect like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <body>
     <a href="" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'" >go</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tryed something like:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
         window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    })
</script>
```

But in this way a dialog box appears , if you type yes then you will go to http://www.example.com , else you will go to www.google.com.
It's possible use frames to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Why not re-write the existing event on the A-tag?

Comment: i want build an external tool. i can manipulate the html code parsing it, but i can't parse other javascript files